# Debugging PHP, from NetBeans using XDebug and XAMPP

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I have followed [this document](https://alteridem.net/2010/11/10/debugging-php-on-windows-with-netbeans/):

This is my php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I am running Apache using XAMPP on port 9000:
[image]

from NetBeans when I do: Debug -> Debug Project

I get the following:

> Port 9,000 is already in occupied. Configure the IDE to use another
> port?

[image]

XAMPP is the software that is using port 9000 thousand. What do I need to do here? Should I change the XDebug port to 9001? Tools -> Options:

[image]
If I do this, I would also need to change php.ini and change the XDebug port to 9001.

Or should I keep using port 9000? I have been different settings, but not able to hit my break point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the debugger running:

1. When prompted with:

> Port 9,000 is already occupied Configure the IDE to use another port?

Click Yes (alternatively you can open the setting from *Tools -> Options*: Choose *PHP -> Debugging*)

Set debugger Port to 9001.

[image]

2. update php.ini to have port 9001

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

3. Restart XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Netbeans for years to code PHP and xdebug has always been a pain. I cant even give you any pointers.

But I switched last year to VS code and I can honestly say that it improved my code, and xdebug is actually easy to connect, and fun to use.

I recommend you give it a try.